# ListView hidden behind ToolBar, and Floating action button hidden behind ListView

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

My FAB will shows up in the design window in android studio but does not show up when I actually run the app.

In addition, I have a ListView item which I have specified should sit below the toolbar, yet when I run the app it is partially hidden behind the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:cb_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[how the layout appears in design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o4Kn.png)

[how app appears when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFk81.jpg)

What do?

Answer (score 1):

> My FAB will shows up in the design window in android studio but does not show up when I actually run the app.

**Try moving the FAB above the ListView in the code** like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:cb_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, Android renders layouts in a certain order, based on their order in the XML markup.

> In addition, I have a ListView item which I have specified should sit below the toolbar, yet when I run the app it is partially hidden behind the toolbar.

**Change the listView's height to `wrap_content`** (I changed it to be like this in above code as well, but here it is again):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />
```

Because the ListView is a sibling of the Toolbar, when the height is set to `match_parent` it fills the whole screen, including the area under the toolbar.

Comment: Also make sure that you are setting your toolbar as an `ActionBar` in your code.

Comment: I implemented both of those changes but to no avail. Still encountering both issues.

Comment: this is my toolbar java code in MainActivity 
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

Comment: Yes, the editor in design view is updating with all of the changes I make, but not when I run the app

Comment: What device are you testing it on?

Comment: Motorola moto x 2nd gen, running android 6.0, API 23

Comment: I have run it on a few emulators running later versions of android and I have the same issues

Comment: What is the purpose of using the CircleButton class over the AppCompat FloatingActionButton class?